# How do I find() a specific field to mongodb through angular?

Tags: angular, mongodb, get, find, local-storage

I'm trying to display the products that a person has placed bids on. Example data would be

```
{
"product": "Test"
"details": "Testing"
"currentbid": 200
"bidname": "June"
}

{
"product": "Test2"
"details": "Testing2"
"currentbid": 150
"bidname": "Estelle"
}

{
"product": "Test3"
"details": "Testing3"
"currentbid": 20
"bidname": "June"
}
```

So I'm trying to display products that only June has bid on. The 'bidname' field is recorded in local storage.

I've tried to code it out but it's likely that it's completely wrong. Please help.

api.js

```
router.get('/quotes/:bidname', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('carDetails').find( {"bidname":ObjectId(req.params.bidname)}, (err,
        results) => {
        res.send(results);
        });
  });
```

service.ts

```
export class RentserviceService {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  quotesUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000/api/quotes";

  getNamePost(bidname: string) {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.quotesUrl+ '/' + bidname);
  }
}
```

component.ts

```
export class DisplaybidsComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Product Details';
  quotes: any = [];
      
  constructor(private rentService: RentserviceService) {
    this.rentService.getNamePost(localStorage.getItem("username")).subscribe(quotes => {
      this.quotes = quotes;
    });
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1 style="font-family:monospace;"> {{title}} </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let quote of quotes" style="font-family:monospace;" class="city">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">Product Name: {{ quote.product }}</h2>
        <h2 class="card-text">Details: {{ quote.details}}</h2>
        <h2 class="card-text">Current Bid: {{ quote.currentbid}}</h2> 
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please describe the problem you are facing. Are you getting errors?

Comment: The `bidname` fields in the sample documents appear to be plain strings, why are they converted to `ObjectId`s?

Comment: @JudsonTerrell The error is 404, it's likely because my api.js is wrong. I have changed it to `db.collection('carDetails').find( {"bidname":(req.params.bidname)}` but it still triggers 404. Is there another ts/js I forgot to change?

Comment: What server are you running the api on and what port? Also can you put a console log to make sure the api is even getting hit? Above the db.collection…. It might be helpful if you share you server js file or the rest of your entry point file. MINUS CREDENTIALS